# Opening files from filepaths on windows

Tags: windows, file, typeerror

I try to define a function that will take a file path and turn it into a string.
This is the defenition I came up with:

```
    def get_book(file_path):
        '''Takes a file path and returns the entire book as a string.'''
        with open(file_path, 'r', 'utf-8') as infile:
            content = infile.read()
            return content

    AnnaKarenina = get_book('../Python/Data/books/AnnaKarenina.txt')
```

I now get TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

I also tried using the os.path, different kinds of slashes and other tricks for opening files with windows, but that all returns the error file not found.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding parameters of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function is a named parameters, so you have to specify it like this :

```
 def get_book(file_path):
        '''Takes a file path and returns the entire book as a string.'''
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            content = infile.read()
            return content

AnnaKarenina = get_book('../Python/Data/books/AnnaKarenina.txt')
```

Comment: To clarify, `encoding` is not a keyword-only parameter, but it is the fourth positional parameter, and the OP is passing it as the third parameter `buffering`, which requires an integer. Passing `encoding` as a keyword argument avoids having to pass a value for `buffering`.

Comment: FYI, idiomatic Python style does not use spaces around a keyword-argument assignment, e.g. it's `encoding='utf-8'`, unless it's an annotated parameter in a function definition, e.g. `parameter: str = None`. Refer to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), "Whitespace in Expressions and Statements" -> "Other Recommendations".

Comment: Thx for those advices. I edited the answer to respect the PEP8